# TensorFlow Lite model testing: right code, probabilities of classes

Tags: c++, tensorflow, tensorflow-lite

I'm trying to test TensorFlow lite c++ code with TensorflowLite model. Model gets 256*256 array of floats (spectrogram or image) and do some inference on this data. The TF Lite model is designed to solve the problem of classification into 5 classes. It was derived from a conventional TF model by conversion. I use TF Lite 2.0.

[Test model](https://yadi.sk/d/e4dqzVgaozYZBg)

This is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include "../tensorflow/tensorflow/lite/interpreter.h"
#include "../tensorflow/tensorflow/lite/model.h"
#include "../tensorflow/tensorflow/lite/kernels/register.h"
#include "../tensorflow/tensorflow/lite/op_resolver.h"
#include <cstdlib>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{

    const char* filename = argv[1];

    std::unique_ptr<tflite::FlatBufferModel> model = tflite::FlatBufferModel::BuildFromFile(filename);

    tflite::ops::builtin::BuiltinOpResolver resolver;
    std::unique_ptr<tflite::Interpreter> interpreter;
    tflite::InterpreterBuilder(*model, resolver)(&interpreter);

    interpreter->SetNumThreads(4);
    interpreter->AllocateTensors();

    for(int i = 0; i < 256*256; i++){
    float input = rand() % 10 + rand() % 10;
            interpreter->typed_input_tensor<float>(0)[i] = input;
            //printf("%f ", input);
    }
    //printf("\n");

    interpreter->Invoke();
    int output = interpreter->outputs()[0];

    printf("%d ",  output);

    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        float output  = interpreter->typed_output_tensor<float>(0)[i];
        printf("%f ", (output));
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

I have some questions:

- how to organize the input data (how to apply a two-dimensional spectrogram to the input of the model)?
- how to get the output probability of classes in right way?
- did I write the right code to test the model?

Comment: The question is rather broad (three questions, actually), and not completely clear...  Starting with your last question, what do you mean "the right code"? I haven't used tflite, but the code seems reasonable... Is it not working/compiling for you? And the code would depend on the model code anyway. Same for questions 1 and 2, how you provide and receive the the data depends on how the model is written... Or do you have a problem with the C++ API? Please explain clearly what is the specific issue you are facing, or the unexpected output you are obtaining, if any.

Comment: @jdehesa, Hello! Thanks for the comment! My doubts about the following code: I'm not sure I properly load the spectrogram in the model as two-dimensional spectrogram, and the data I load a one-dimensional way, also I'm not sure about the correct output of the model.

Comment: So, the code seems indeed to be loading 256 x 256 random numbers into the input, through [`typed_input_tensor`](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/api_docs/cc/class/tflite/interpreter#typed_input_tensor), which gives you a pointer to the input tensor data (in [row-major order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row-_and_column-major_order)). Then, after running with `Invoke`, you read and print five values from the output, similarly accessed through [`typed_output_tensor`](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/api_docs/cc/class/tflite/interpreter#typed_output_tensor). It seems correct, as a test...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code looks about right. And since Tensorflow Lite looks at tensors in row-major format, your way of assigning inputs seems reasonable.

You probably don't need this:

```
int output = interpreter->outputs()[0];

printf("%d ",  output);
```

Otherwise, things look okay.
If you pre-process the input image/spectogram the same way you did during training, you should obtain the outputs you expect.